# Hugo "Error while watching: short read in readEvents()" - unnecessary page refreshes

Tags: hugo, fsutil

The specific error is:
"Error while watching: short read in readEvents()"
this error is being output by the hugo server.

The phenomena this causes is continuous local server "Change detected, rebuilding site".

In trying to find a resolution (not to create a red-herring, but at least something I found), it seems that fsutil is used to watch for changes and this could possibly be related to fsutil, but this exceeded my limited understanding.

I am using Hugo, specifically:

```
hugo v0.82.1-60618210 
VendorInfo=gohugoio GOOS="windows" 
GOARCH="amd64" 
GOVERSION="go1.16"windows/amd64 
BuildDate=2021-04-20T11:02:50Z
```

A custom theme, relatively simple, I've created myself.

```
General size/content:
                   | EN
-------------------+------
  Pages            |  93
  Paginator pages  |   0
  Non-page files   |   3
  Static files     | 322
  Processed images |   0
  Aliases          |   2
  Sitemaps         |   1
  Cleaned          |   0
```

The issue being I am using hugo server to locally develop before pushing via git to a github repo that is connected to Amplify (AWS), so I do need that local environment and the continuous obsessive refreshing is making it hard to use.

This is my first time posting a question.

Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Please also note I am unable to post the repo, but any specific information I would be more than happy to provide (sorry if this is problematic or if their is another method I should use to supply information).

Thank you for everyone's time.

-- additional information if it assists: from Hugo server:
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x20 pc=0x18938d3]

goroutine 357 [running]

seems to stem from newWatcher which would be fsutil I believe...

Just trying to give more data if helpful.

Comment: As of 15 May - I've managed to make this go away. Not intentionally though. I've come to the point of understanding that the panic runtime error, is from Go, and it's stating essentially that somehow the memory allocation is, well wrong (something wrong with my code possibly), I had to install Hugo extended to use PostCSS, so I did that, with hugo extended, I no longer get this error. It's not really a handling nor a real understanding, but, it's information... :|

Comment: Since 2021-April-12 (probably earlier), I also am getting the error you mentioned and the hugo server is constantly rebuilding everything. I didn't reply earlier because I'm trying to debug this myself but here's some info that may be helpful:

1] I only use hugo extended.
2] The problems happened with `hugo serve -v --verboseLog --path-warnings --ignoreCache`
3] The problems do not seem to be happening with `hugo serve -v --verboseLog --path-warnings --ignoreCache --gc --noHTTPCache --disableBrowserError` (last 3 flags are my current experiment)

Comment: Update 18 May, I'm not getting this error anymore. I didn't save, verbatim, the previous error which is my mistake. What possibly seems to have been an inadvertent change is the "watch list" - in this case it's only {content, data and themes}. n m, can you send through your watchlist? (Also is if ignore cache is fixing this with a garbage collect, my gut feeling is that the compiled/public folders and quantity of file is perhaps creating an issue?)

Comment: Sublime... Not very helpful for you, pardon. - Possibly I'm going to post on the hugo discourse as they are more into the "root" of the matter and quite helpful for such things.